# How to convert from string to char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, alphabetical

I have this code, in which I need to input some data, and then the program needs to put the data in alphabetical order.

The problem is that I can't convert `string name` to the `char*` variables `s1` and `s2`.

Data to input:

```
1 Cheile_Dobrogei 45 25 200
2 Vulcanii_Noroiosi 46 25 50
3 Cetatea_Istra 45 25 100
4 Barajul_Siriu 51 30 50
5 Castelul_Peles 45 30 150
6 Castelul_Bran 53 30 150
7 Voronet 54 35 200
8 Cheile_Bicazului 55 35 100
9 Manastirea_Varatec 56 35 50
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct obiectiv {
    int id;
    string name;
    double latitud; 
    double longitud; 
    double cost_vizitare;
};

int main()
{
    int i, k, temp;
    struct obiectiv ob[9];
    cout << "Introduceti obiectivele(maxim 9): ID NAME LATITUD LONGITUD PRICE" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        cin >> ob[i].id >> ob[i].name >> ob[i].latitud >> ob[i].longitud >> ob[i].cost_vizitare;
    }

    struct obiectiv tempob[9];
    struct obiectiv t[9];
    for (i = 0;i < 9;i++) {
        tempob[i] = ob[i];
    }
    int sorted;
    for (k = 0; k < 9;k++) {
        sorted = 1;
        for (i = 0;i < 9;i++) {
            char* s1 = tempob[i].name;
            char* s2 = tempob[i + 1].name;
            if (strcmp(s1,s2) > 0) {
                t[i] = ob[i];
                tempob[i] = tempob[i + 1];
                tempob[i + 1] = t[i];
                sorted = 0;
            }
        }
        if (sorted == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "alphabetical order: ";
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        cout << tempob[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char* s1 = tempob[i].name.c_str();`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `c_str()` returns a `const char*`, which can't be assigned to a `char*`.  So either `s1` and `s2` need to be declared as `const char*` instead (preferred), or the pointer returned by `c_str()` needs to be type-casted to `char*` using `const_cast` (less preferred).

Comment: Why do you even use C-strings? Use strings `const std::string &s1 = ...;`, `const std::string &s2 = ...;` and replace `if (strcmp(s1,s2) > 0)` with `if (s1 > s2) {`

Comment: So why do you need a `char *` rather than a `const char *`? And why aren't you using the comparison operators built into `std::string`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau actually you just need `char* s1 = &tempob[i].name[0];` if you really want `char*`. No need for a `const_cast`

Comment: @phuclv well, if you want to nit-pick, you should use `char* s1 = tempob[i].name.data();` instead, but that only works in C++17 and later. But there is no reason to use `char*` in this case anyway, since they are being passed to `strcmp()`, which takes `const char*` parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to even use C-strings in your code. Change 3 lines

```
char* s1 = ...;
char* s2 = ...;
```

to

```
const std::string &s1 = ...;
const std::string &s2 = ...;
```

and

```
if (strcmp(s1,s2) > 0)
```

to

```
if (s1 > s2) {
```

and you can keep `std::string`:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct obiectiv {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    double latitud; 
    double longitud; 
    double cost_vizitare;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<obiectiv, 9> ob;
    std::cout << "Introduceti obiectivele(maxim 9): ID NAME LATITUD LONGITUD PRICE" << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        std::cin >> ob[i].id >> ob[i].name >> ob[i].latitud >> ob[i].longitud >> ob[i].cost_vizitare;
    }

    auto tempob = ob;
    
    for (int k = 0; k < 9;k++) {
        bool sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            const auto &s1 = tempob[i].name;
            const auto &s2 = tempob[i + 1].name;
            if (s1 > s2) {
                std::swap(tempob[i], tempob[i + 1]);
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
        if (sorted) {
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "alphabetical order: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        std::cout << tempob[i].name << '\n';
    }
}
```

There was an error in the swap logic. I replaced it with `std::swap` to fix the error.

Using `std::array` instead of C-arrays allows you to copy an array without loop.

I also changed some bad styles in the code. I removed `using namespace std;`, `struct` in front of a `struct` initialization, unnecessary `std::endl` and I made `sorted` a boolean.

Comment: thank you! ive followed what you said and it is working.(+ some minor changes to code because the loop returned me code -416494179(random numbers) insead of 0)

Comment: @SergiuLuca _"some minor changes"_??? The code works for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/wD7i358aaXdpz8SD

Comment: it works now, exactly like you made it. idk what happened o_o

Comment: I would just get rid of `s1` and `s2` altogether: `if (tempob[i].name > tempob[i + 1].name) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this(convert from string to char*) in many different ways:

1.Use const_cast operator:

```
std::string str = "from string to char*";
char *chr = const_cast<char*>(str.c_str());
std::cout << chr << "\n";
```

2.Use strcpy():

```
std::string str = "from string to char*";
char *chr = strcpy(new char[str.length() + 1],str.c_str());
std::cout << chr << "\n";
```

3.Use copy():

```
std::string str = "from string to char*";
int length = str.size();
char *chr = new char[length + 1];
std::copy(str.begin(),str.end(),chr);
chr[length] = "\0";//add end of line
std::cout << chr << "\n";
delete[] chr; //don't forget!
```

4.Use contigous storage of std::string:

```
std::string str = "from string to char*";
char *chr = &*str.begin();
std::cout << chr << "\n";
```